# Magento 2 custom customer attribute's values not getting saved in database?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I've added two custom attributes for customer registration page (Alternate email & Alternate number) in a new module (through : app/code/.../Setup/InstallData.php).

I have designed its 'view' inside a custom theme (by overriding register.phtml). I can now see new fields on the registration page. However the data inside new fields (alternate email and number) is not getting saved inside database.

'customer_entity_int' saves '0' value..
'customer_entity_varchar' saves nothing..

[image]

Here in the screen you can see the value is saved as '0'. The attribute_id 132 is for 'Alternate Contact Number' on the registration page. So I expect the value to hold the data which I'm entering on the frontend registration page.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you add customer attributes using custom extension ?

Comment: I added it through a custom module (app/code/.../Setup/InstallData.php) and made it's 'view' through a customized new theme by overriding the 'phtml' file..

Comment: Before saving the data.. print the model and check if your values are there.

Comment: Did you reindex and clear cache ?

Comment: If its still show proper values after printing the model try to log the query and check how the query is getting generated and see if your values are there in that query. To do that open to app/etc/di.xml ... search for `Quiet`, You will find only 1 occurrence and change that to `File`. Now open the file `Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\File` and set `$logAllQueries` to true. and refresh the browser and open the generated file `var/debug/db.log`. Find your query and check the query.

Comment: If still your values show properly in query then it must be an issue with db fields datatype. Maybe you are providing wrong datatype to db fields. Or an cache issue.

Comment: Well! I tried clearing cache and reindexing but it is still storing '0' value for 'int' and nothing inside the 'varchar'..I have updated the description and added a screen. Please see if you can relate..Thanks

Answer (score 29):

You have probably solved your issue but for people who come here from google as me, there is a solution:

> When creating the customer attribute, please take care of the following things:

> Attribute is added to the attribute set, group

```
customer_eav_attribute
eav_entity_attribute
```

> Attribute is assigned to customer forms

```
customer_form_attribute
```

> And the last one the most important as somehow, people just skip over it and wondering why the customer attribute does not want to save from the backend: **Please make sure to set "is_system" flag in "customer_eav_attribute" table to 0, otherwise the attribute will not be saved.**

> It can be done by setting the attribute option to "system" => 0 in attribute parameters inside the install/upgrade script.

**Don't forget to flush your cache after all!**

***Solution URL:***

[direct link to solution](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1393#issuecomment-571117463)

Comment: i can save attribute by is_system = 0, but can you let me know why we need to make it 0? as its 1 by default in table

Comment: @bhargav shastri, because is_system attribute belongs to Magento

Comment: yes i got it thanks

Comment: Superb! Thanks kudos!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone will be here searching for the solution. I had the same issue and this [comment](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1393#issuecomment-119175268) worked for me.

> To avoid this you must specify additional parameters for the
>   attribute.
>
> - attribute_set_id
> - attribute_group_id

```
    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_code')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);
    $attribute->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please follow the below URL:

Anyone searching for the solution. I had the same issue & this below URL worked for me.....

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/320918/85990

Answer (score 0):

A.Maksymiuk's answer worked like a charm. Here the SQL scripts (MySQL/Maria DB) I've created in order to fix the issue with my attribute:

```
# Sets up attribute_id to be changed
select @ATTRIBUTE_ID := attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code  = 'attribute_code';

# Refence attribute_id to be used to create the group (here customer email) 
SELECT @REFENCENCE_ATTRIBUTE_ID := attribute_id FROM eav_attribute where entity_type_id = 1 AND attribute_code = 'email';

# Verifies it exists in the customer table
SELECT * FROM customer_eav_attribute WHERE attribute_id = @ATTRIBUTE_ID;

# Fixes is_system issue
UPDATE customer_eav_attribute SET is_system = 0 WHERE attribute_id = @ATTRIBUTE_ID;

# Fixes group issue using same values as the customer email attribute
INSERT INTO eav_entity_attribute 
SELECT null, entity_type_id, attribute_set_id, attribute_group_id, @ATTRIBUTE_ID, 100
FROM eav_entity_attribute 
WHERE attribute_id IN (@REFENCENCE_ATTRIBUTE_ID) 
LIMIT 1;
```

Cheers,

Renato