# Magento2 Migrated custom customer attribute is not saving the value

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I have migrated Magento data from version 1.9.0.1 to version 2.3.5-p1. In 1.9.0.1 setup there was a custom customer attribute created called mobile_no. The data and the attribute automatically created in my M2 setup. The mobile_no data is also visible in the M2 admin. But when I try to edit the number and save it, It saves the old value its not taking the updated one. Can anyone help me with this? I have to call this attribute in the frontend registration form.

Comment: Thank you. This look like the answer for my issue. Where, I'm sorry that I'm new to magento 2 development. Can you please let me know where do i place this data patch file, and how to run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking multiple things and digging down the database finally I found the issue, hence sharing the answer. The issue was after the migration the entry was missing in the `eav_entity_attribute` table for the respective attribute. Updated the attribute using the below Data patch and fixed the issue. Now I am able to save the value.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

/**
 * Patch for the Customer Attribute
 *
 * Patch Class to update the migrated field mobile_no in the `eav_entity_attribute` table. 
 */

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Zend_Validate_Exception;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

/**
 * Patch Class to update the mobile_no in the `eav_entity_attribute` table.
 */
class UpdateEavMobileNoAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * AddressAttribute constructor.
     *
     * @param Config              $eavConfig
     * @param EavSetupFactory     $eavSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config $eavConfig,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Create strategic account customer attribute
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    public function apply(): void
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

        $customerEntity = $this->eavConfig->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('customer', 'mobile_no');

        $customAttribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit']
        ]);
        $customAttribute->save();

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Superb!! kudos!

Comment: Worked perfectly to solve my problem, thanks. Just one thing I noticed: I don't think you're actually using the *EavSetupFactory* you're loading here!